# localStorage returning NaN (rather than a Number, or nothing at all)

Tags: javascript, html

I've been trying to get `localStorage` working, yet continue to be plagued with errors. I've seen several methods for working with local storage, and tried several, yet none some to work as expected.

My most recent foray has been based on [this example](http://www.w3schools.com/html/tryit.asp?filename=tryhtml5_webstorage_local_clickcount) from W3Schools, but it does not seem to work either.

```
var difficulty = 0;
var highscore = 0; 

function retrieveLocalData() {
    if(typeof(Storage)!=="undefined") {
        if(localStorage.highscore) { highscore = parseInt(localStorage.highscore); }
        if(localStorage.difficulty) { difficulty = parseFloat(localStorage.difficulty); }
    }
}

function storeLocalData() {
    if(typeof(Storage)!=="undefined") {
        localStorage.highscore = highscore; 
        localStorage.difficulty = difficulty; 
    }
}
```

What I expect is `storeLocalData()` to check if there is support for localStorage, if so store the `highscore` and `difficulty` in `localStorage`. I expect `retrieveLocalData()` to check if there is support for localStorage, check if `highscore` or `difficulty` respectively have been stored, and if so, retrieve the values, parsing them as an Int or a Float respectively with `parseInt` and `parseFloat`.

During tests, `highscore` is output as NaN.

Are my expectations and assumptions incorrect? I'm not sure why this behaviour is occuring. Thanks.

---

Edit 1:

I deleted all the localStorage values, and added `console.log()` of the values of `highscore` at each point before or after modification of the value. Immediately before entering `retrieveLocalData()` the value is 0, as expected, however after exiting `retrieveLocalData()` the value is NaN.

Edit 2:

I altered my `if` statement to `if(!isNaN(parseInt(localStorage.highscore)))` as per apsillers' suggestion. Code is now working fine :)

Comment: What is the value of `highscore` just before `localStorage.highscore = highscore;`? I'm guessing it's a string with non-numeric characters (or just an empty string).

Comment: Hmm... You're right, it was NaN in one test... I'm not sure why. `highscore` is only changed either by `retrieveLocalData()` or `if(score>highscore) { highscore = score; }`, however score itself is initialised to 0 and only affected by increments of 10 (i.e. `score=score+10;` so I'm not sure what the cause could be. 

Thank you for your insight.

Answer (score 2):

Your specified code works correctly if tested on it's own. What you're likely doing is making a scoping mistake where your `highscore` is actually `undefined`, so try checking in the developer tools (F12) the resources tab (chrome) where you can inspect what's inside the localstorage. If the values are incorrect there then you will need inspect your `storeLocalData` function, alternatively it could also be the case that nothing is stored yet, or that literally NaN is stored if you called your `retrieveLocalData` before your `storeLocalData` after which `undefined` got retrieved first (as NaN, due to the parseFloat) and next got saved (after which you get stuck in a loop, so try changing NaN in that case to 0 and 0).

Comment: Ah thank you, I think my assumptions are wrong in that case! `retrieveLocalData()` is called immediately, I had assumed that `if(localStorage.highscore)` meant that the body of the `if` statement would only work if there was a pre-existing key-value pair... but it now occurs to me that (I assume) the body of the `if` statement would in fact execute if the if statement successfully created a key-value pair, so it would then retrieve `undefined`... Is that the case?

Comment: (In which case, I should use `if(typeof(localStorage.highscore)==number)` instead? :)

Comment: If it's really undefined then it won't get retrieved, but if by some mistake during development it has become the string undefined or the string NaN then it will get retrieved and you will get stuck in a loop sort of, so yeah, your last proposal is the safest bet, but try deleting the items from the localStorage and check if that already fixes the problem (wouldn't be too surprised).

Comment: @ShimmerGeek `typeof localStorage.highscore == "number"` will always be `false`, because values in `Storage` objects are always strings. You should perhaps instead try `!isNaN(parseInt(localStorage.highscore))`? Furthermore, `undefined` is a so-called "falsey" value, so `if(undefined)` is treated the same as `if(false)`.

Comment: Oops, you're absolutely right@apsillers, my bad, but you could do the conversion to a number and not write it to the relevant variable only if not `NaN`.

Answer (score 0):

I really liked this way of doing it:

```js
const highscore = parseInt(localStorage.getItem("highscore")) || 0
```

In this way the highscore const will contain a number which we can easily compare to our current score.

Comment: I prefer `const highscore = +(localStorage.getItem( 'highscore' ) ?? 0)` tbh

Comment: @somethinghere, does not make any difference in this case?

Comment: If it made a difference it wouldn't really be a preference.